# running Wordpress from EFS on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-efs

I'm fairly new to the AWS world and I was wondering about the limitations of running a scalable wordpress installation on Elastic beanstalk from and EFS mount.

I got the filesystem to mount correctly, but how do I make it so that Elastic Beanstalk deploys the application to the EFS folder? can I just mount the EFS to /var/www/html? or is there a way to switch out the document root to say.. /var/www/wordpress and have Elastic Beanstalk deploy the application there?... any direction would be greatly apreciated

Comment: Normally you  app will be deploy to `/var/app/current`

Comment: Ohh man, I completely forgot I had asked this last year. I should post an answer to this lol. I went from a complete noob to deploying a fully elastic environment with auto failover and Continuous development using bitbucket’s pipelines. It’s crazy how much you can grow in a year

Comment: Yes, you should share your finding

Comment: yes, you should *really* share your findings.